# Group by with conditions python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, pandas-groupby

i Have a dataframe with two columns. Sample of the df is attached below.

```
id  Content
21  John
25  kevin
26  john
28  levis
21  john
21  carls
25  kevin
29  john
25  carls
25  john
29  kevin
21  carls
21  carls
25  john
```

What I want to do is **groupby using id and set their occurrences** and if it contains **john and carls combination, assied 1 for that particular id.**

```
Id  Content
21  John
    John
    carls
    carls
    carls
25  kevin
    kevin
    carls
    John
    John
26  john
28  levis
29  john
    kevin
```

Final required dataframe:

```
Id  Result
21  1
25  1
26  0
28  0
29  0
```

I did the groupby part but don't know how to get the final required output df.

Really appreciate your help !!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`df.Groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with [`Series.unique`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.unique.html) and [`Series.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.apply.html):

```
In [2511]: x = df.groupby('id').Content.unique().reset_index()
In [2514]: x['Result'] = x.Content.apply(lambda x: 1 if 'john' in x and 'carls' in x else 0)

In [2516]: x.drop('Content', 1, inplace=True)

In [2517]: x
Out[2517]: 
   id  Result
0  21       1
1  25       1
2  26       0
3  28       0
4  29       0
```

**EDIT:** For checking the `order` as well, you can do this:

```
In [2539]: x['Result'] = x.Content.apply(lambda x: 1 if ('john', 'carls') in zip(x, x[1:]) else 0)
In [2541]: x.drop('Content', 1, inplace=True)

In [2542]: x
Out[2542]: 
   id  Result
0  21       1
1  25       0
2  26       0
3  28       0
4  29       0
```

Comment: Great... Thanks a lot.. Is there a way to get if and only if John appears first and then charls? I mean If so, only id 25 get 1 and all others are 0.

Comment: @kevin Please check the updated `EDIT` part answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can try using `set.issubset` with `groupby` here to check membership of both `john` and `carl` in each group :

```
f = lambda x: {"john","carls"}.issubset(set(x.str.lower()))
out = df.groupby("id")["Content"].agg(f).rename("result").astype(int).reset_index()
```

---

```
print(out)

   id  result
0  21       1
1  25       1
2  26       0
3  28       0
4  29       0
```

EDIT for question asked in comments, first sort with id ,then you can map with a dictionary and then check condition whether a value is lesser then the next row present in any of the group, then using the condition we had previously we can se an `&` condition:

```
df = df.sort_values("id")
d = {"john":1,"carls":2}
s = df['Content'].str.lower().map(d)
c1 = s.shift().lt(s).groupby(df['id']).any()

f = lambda x: set(d.keys()).issubset(set(x.str.lower()))
out = ((df.groupby("id")["Content"].agg(f) & c1).astype(int)
        .rename("result").reset_index())
```

---

```
print(out)

   id  result
0  21       1
1  25       0
2  26       0
3  28       0
4  29       0
```

Comment: Great... Thanks a lot.. Is there a way to get if and only if John appears first and then charls? I mean If so, only id 25 get 1 and all others are 0.

Comment: @kevin I have updated my answer. Please check if thats what you needed. Although we should try and ask 1 question per question :-)